# How to perform coalesce on nullable columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, mysqli

I have three date columns which represented by strings.

Columns `date1`, and `date2` are nullable columns.
I want to order then in the following order - date1, date2, date3.

Is this a good workaround:

```
Select coalesce (NULLIF(date1,''), NULLIF(date2,''), date3)
```

Comment: I can think of no other answer but "yes, that look good".

Comment: You should use an adequate data type (`[SMALL]DATE[TIME][2][OFFSET]`) to store date/time values.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review.

Answer (score -2):

If you store NULL for missing dates and never store blank strings, the NullIF is superfluous, just do

```
Select coalesce (date1, date2, date3)
```

Comment: This doesn't meet the OP's requirement.  If date1 is an empty string, then this code will return that empty string rather than date2, as intended.